# Why am I unable to acess properties of my object model?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

For some odd reason, I am unable to access the properties of this object EVEN if I cast it as its model type.  Does anyone have an idea as to why?  (It may be obvious, but I'm pretty new to C# so please be patient! :o) )

```
Users currentUser = new Users();            
currentUser = (from x in db_tc.Users where x.Id == Convert.ToInt32(User.Identity.Name) select x);
```

When I call `currentUser`, I am only able to access the CRUD methods and a `List<Users>` property called `usrList`.  I didn't create the list definition, so I imagine this is some piece of the Entity framework that is automagically created.

I did try casting `currentUser` with `(Users)` prior to the entity query, it didn't help at all.

Comment: Why are you doing this `Convert.ToInt32(User.Identity.Name)` your usernames are always numbers? Or is your ID column the actual name, not an identity column?

Comment: @Jay this may be a bit hacky, but the userID for the corresponding user in the USERS table is currently placed in User.Identity.Name.   I just learned about the 'UserData' property of the Authentication Cookie, so I'll be revising it in the near future...I just wanted to figure this piece out first.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's because you've only created the query, you haven't actually executed it. Add `Single()` (or `First()` etc.) to get the result:

```
var currentUser = (from x in db_tc.Users where x.Id == Convert.ToInt32(User.Identity.Name) select x).SingleOrDefault();
```

- [`Single()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb156472.aspx): Gets the first element of the sequence, but will throw an exception if no element is found *or* if the sequence has more than one element.
- [`First()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348657.aspx): Gets the first element of the sequence, but will throw an exception if no element is found.
- [`SingleOrDefault()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.queryable.singleordefault.aspx) and [`FirstOrDefault()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb301896.aspx): Same as above, but will return `default(T)` instead of throwing on the empty sequence.

This "deferred execution" aspect of LINQ is probably the most difficult part to understand. The basic idea is that you can build up a *query* using the query operations (`Where()`, `Select()`, etc.), and then you can execute that query to actually get its results, using one of the non-deferred execution operations (`Single()`, `ToList()`, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

The operation you have here will return a list of matches the DB will return, it is a collection.
If you intend on it only returning a single record append `.First();` to the end of your linq query.

Also remove this line `Users currentUser = new Users();`
and add this `var currentUser =...`

Answer (score 0):

Some more tips from the "good LINQ practices" wagon...

LINQ should "usually" return var, then you convert to the data type you are expecting. Another good practice I have found is to immediately validate the return from LINQ, as any usage without validation is highly exception prone. For instance:

```
var qUser = (from x in db.Users select x);

if (qUser != null && currentUser.Count() > 0)
{
    List<User> users = (List<User>)qUser.ToList();
    ... process users result ...
}
```

The not null and count greater than 0 check should be *required* after each LINQ query. ;)

And don't forget to wrap in try-catch for SqlException!

Comment: `qUser != null` is unnecessary. The constructed query will never be `null`. I'm not sure I follow your advice here.

Comment: really?  so anonymous vars are preferred when referencing a specific object type?   i was under the impression you were supposed to specify the type of object you are returning if possible.  e.g. `List<Type> objList = (from u in db_tc.Users where u.ID == userID select u).ToList();`   or    even `Users qUser = (from x in db.Users select x);`

Comment: @Bob using `var` is *way* easier when dealing with LINQ; there are so many different types actually floating around, it's tough to get it just right. And of course if your query produces an anonymous type, it's actually required.

Comment: @dlev, I apologize, you are correct, you do not need to check `qUser != null`. But I always do check for null after the call to ToList(). Basically the thing I was harping at was 1) use `var` type with LINQ results, and 2) check the results of your database queries; the database query could return no results and you want to avoid pesky exceptions from cropping up.